# Extending native JavaScript Promise with cancellation support

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

**Updated**, below is [a more current and simple version](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/247796/35474) of this. Also, if you track the progress of TC39's "ECMAScript Cancellation" proposal, [this thread](https://github.com/rbuckton/prex/issues/3) might be worth checking out.

---

I'm playing with [Promise Extensions for JavaScript (prex)](https://github.com/rbuckton/prex#readme) library and I like it a lot. Amongst other things, this library appears to be a prototype behind the current [ECMA TC39 proposal for cancellation](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-cancellation) and it uses the familiar cancellation token approach, popularized by .NET Task API.

I want to extend the standard [Promise class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) with cancellation support, similar to how it is [implemented in Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/cancellation.html) (i.e., with an optional `oncancel` callback) but using [prex.CancellationToken](https://github.com/rbuckton/prex/blob/master/docs/cancellation.md#class-cancellationtoken).

Here is a draft that can be run with NodeJS:

```
const prex = require('prex');

class CancellablePromise extends Promise {
  constructor(executor, token) {
    if (!token) {
      // if no token supplied, just delegate to the parent class
      super(executor);
      return;
    }
    
    const observeCancellation = async () => {
      // prex.Deferred is similar to TaskCompletionSource in .NET
      const deferred = new prex.Deferred();

      executor(
        deferred.resolve, 
        deferred.reject, 
        cancelListener => 
          deferred.cancelListener = cancelListener);  

      const registration = token.register(() => {
        try {
          // capture the CancelError
          token.throwIfCancellationRequested();
        }
        catch (cancelError) {
          try {
            // the token cancellation callback is synchronous,
            // and so is the executor-provided cancelListener callback
            deferred.cancelListener && deferred.cancelListener(cancelError);
            // reject here if cancelListener has not resolved/rejected it
            deferred.reject(cancelError);
          }
          catch (error) {
            // in case cancelListener throws
            deferred.reject(error);
          }
        }
      });
    
      try {
        return await deferred.promise;
      }
      finally {
        registration.unregister();
      }
    };

    super((resolve, reject) => 
      observeCancellation().then(resolve, reject));
  }
}

// delayWithCancellation
function delayWithCancellation(timeoutMs, token) {
  console.log(`delayWithCancellation: ${timeoutMs}`);

  return new CancellablePromise((resolve, reject, setCancelListener) => {
    token.throwIfCancellationRequested();
    const id = setTimeout(resolve, timeoutMs);
    setCancelListener(e => clearTimeout(id));
  }, token);
}

// main
async function main() {
  const tokenSource = new prex.CancellationTokenSource();
  setTimeout(() => tokenSource.cancel(), 2000); // cancel after 1500ms

  const token = tokenSource.token;

  await delayWithCancellation(1000, token);
  console.log("successfully delayed."); // we should reach here

  await delayWithCancellation(1500, token);
  console.log("successfully delayed."); // we should not reach here
}

main().catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Comment: Assuming you're still using the npm package `prex` for `CancellationTokenSource`, you have a bug. The constructor takes an [iterable of tokens](https://github.com/rbuckton/prex/blob/HEAD/docs/cancellation.md#class-cancellationtokensource), not a single token.

Comment: I don't use it anymore. I've made my own lightweight version without any external dependencies, and more closely modelled after .NET `CancellationTokenSource` and `CancellationToken` than what Prex does.

Comment: The .NET `CancellationTokenSource` class constructor doesn't accept a token at all...

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, that's where I deviated a bit. I didn't want to replicate [`CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.createlinkedtokensource?view=netcore-3.1), so I've made it an option to pass a token to the token source constructor. Do you think it is not a good idea?

Comment: It's just difficult to provide feedback on the class you've posted here if the dependencies (even if you rolled them on your own) aren't documented anywhere publicly. Perhaps consider at least linking to their source?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts will do shortly, I'm currently adding tests and JSDocs.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question after receiving answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: Please, feel free to post a follow-up question.

Answer (score 4):

You can override the executor and can pass an onCancel function to it like following:

```js
class ResponsePromise extends Promise {
  constructor(executor) {
    const onCancel =  (cb) => {
      //using nextTick because we cant use "this" before super()
      setTimeout(()=> {
        this.cancelCb = cb;
      })
    }

    const oExecutor = (resolve, reject) => {
      executor(resolve, reject, onCancel);
    }

    super(oExecutor);
  }
  cancel() {
    if (this.cancelCb) {
      this.cancelCb();
    } else {
      console.warn('onCancel not provided');
    }
  }
```

I have explained this in http://w3.cafe/promise-with-progress-javascript/

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad there's interest in this. I still prefer the `CancelationToken` approach tough, and these days I'm using a [much simplified version of that code](https://gist.github.com/noseratio/141a2df292b108ec4c147db4530379d2). I'll publish that library soon.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, below is my my current version of `CancellablePromise` which *still* uses the "[Promise Extensions for JavaScript (`prex`)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prex)" package.
One notable improvement is using `[Symbol.species]`, more details [on why it's needed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60328122/1768303). A runkit is [here](https://runkit.com/noseratio/cancellablepromise/0.1.5).

```
// https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/207116/35474

const prex = require('prex');

/**
 * Class representing a cancellable promise.
 * @extends Promise
 */
class CancellablePromise extends Promise {
  static get [Symbol.species]() {
    return Promise;
  }

  /**
   * Create an instance of CancellablePromise promise.
   * @param {Function} executor - accepts an object with callbacks 
   *  and a token: { resolve, reject, cancel, token }
   * @param {CancellationToken} token - a cancellation token.
   */
  constructor(executor, token) {
    const withCancellation = async () => {
      const linkedSource = new prex.CancellationTokenSource([token]);

      try {
        const linkedToken = linkedSource.token;
        linkedToken.throwIfCancellationRequested();

        const deferred = new prex.Deferred();
        linkedToken.register(() => deferred.reject(new prex.CancelError()));

        executor({ 
          resolve: value => deferred.resolve(value),
          reject: error => deferred.reject(error),
          cancel: () => linkedSource.cancel(),
          token: linkedToken,
        });
 
        return await deferred.promise;
      }
      finally {
        // this will free the linkedToken registration
        linkedSource.close();
      }
    };

    super((resolve, reject) => withCancellation().then(resolve, reject));
  }
}

//
// An example of using CancellablePromise 
//

// async delay with cancellation
function delayWithCancellation(timeoutMs, token) {
  console.log(`delayWithCancellation: ${timeoutMs}`);

  return new CancellablePromise(d => {
    token.throwIfCancellationRequested();
    const id = setTimeout(d.resolve, timeoutMs);
    d.token.register(() => clearTimeout(id));
  }, token);
}

// main
async function main() {
  const tokenSource = new prex.CancellationTokenSource();
  setTimeout(() => tokenSource.cancel(), 2000); // cancel after 2000ms

  const token = tokenSource.token;

  await delayWithCancellation(1000, token);
  console.log("successfully delayed."); // we should reach here

  await delayWithCancellation(3000, token);
  console.log("successfully delayed."); // we should not reach here
}

main().catch(error => console.log(`Error caught, ${error}`));
```